# Uniform Distribution $Y:=(X+1)^2$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

$X \sim uniform[0,4]$

Another probability variable $Y$ is defined as $Y:=(X+1)^2$. I'm searching for the CDF of $Y$.

Thing's I already know:

If $W:=X+1$ then $W \sim uniform[1,5]$
$Y=W^2$, so $P(Y\le y) = P(W^2\le y) = P(|W|\le \sqrt y)$
Is $P(|W|\le \sqrt(y)) = \frac{\sqrt z+1}{4}$??

Comment: You mean, W uniform on [1,5]?

Comment: I corrected that

Comment: Yes but, unfortunately, not the $\frac{\sqrt{y}+1}4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1<Y<25$ a.s. so $P(Y<y)=0$ for $y<1$ and $P(Y<y)=1$ for $y>25$. Now let $1\leq y \leq 25$.

$$ P(Y<y) = P((X+1)^2<y) = P(X+1 < \sqrt{y}) = P(X<\sqrt{y}-1) = \frac{1}{4}({\sqrt{y}-1}) $$